# I keep getting this error when I click the sign up link in Rails 6: Couldn't find Podcast with 'id'=sign_up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

**This started when I added the show actions in my podcasts controller. Here is the source code:
Any help would be greatly appreciated.**

**controllers:**

```
class PodcastsController < ApplicationController



before_action :find_podcast, only: [:show]



def index
    @podcasts = Podcast.all.order("created_at DESC")
  end

  def show
    @podcast = Podcast.find(params[:id])
  end

  private 
  def find_podcast
        if params[:id].nil?
            @podcast = current_podcast
        else
            @podcast = Podcast.find(params[:id])
        end
    end
end
```

**The podcast model**

```
    class Podcast < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

**routes:**

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


resources :podcasts, only: [:index, :show]
  devise_for :podcasts
  root 'welcome#index'
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

**The views**

```
 <h1> <%= @podcast.title %> </h1>
  <p class="description"> <%= @podcast.description %> </p>
```

Actually, If I click the following links i.e sign up, sign in, edit, sign out
I get these errors
sign in: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PodcastsController#show, Couldn't find Podcast with 'id'=sign_in`

sign up: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PodcastsController#show, Couldn't find Podcast with 'id'=sign_up`

edit: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PodcastsController#show, Couldn't find Podcast with 'id'=edit`

sign out: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PodcastsController#show, Couldn't find Podcast with 'id'=sign_out`

**The devise views:**

```
**app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb**
    <div class="sign_up_banner">
    <h1>Create a podcast, it's 100% free.</h1>
</div>

<div id="form">
    <div class="wrapper_skinny">

    <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

        <div class="field">
          <%= f.label :title %><br />
          <%= f.text_field :title %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %><br />
        <%= f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, autocomplete: "email" %>
      </div>


      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password %>
        <% if @minimum_password_length %>
        <em>(<%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum)</em>
        <% end %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
      </div>

      <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
        <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
      </div>

      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "Sign Up", class: "button button_highlight button_block" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>

    </div>
</div>

**app/views/devise/registrations/edit.html.erb**

<div id="podcast_show">
    <div id="show_banner">
      <div class="wrapper_skinny">
      <h1>The Retrospective</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="links">
    <div class="wrapper_skinny">
        <li>Episodes </li>
        <li> <a href="#"></a>New Episodes </li>
        <li> <%= link_to "Account Settings", edit_podcast_registration_path, class: "current" %> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"></a>View Podcast</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="form">
  <div class="wrapper_skinny"> 
 
  <%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= render "devise/shared/error_messages", resource: resource %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title, autofocus: true %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :description %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :description %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br />
    <%= f.email_field :email %>
  </div>

  <% if devise_mapping.confirmable? && resource.pending_reconfirmation? %>
  <div>Currently waiting confirmation for: <%= resource.unconfirmed_email %></div>
  <% end %>

  <h2>Links</h2>

  <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :itunes %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :itunes %>
  </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :stitcher %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :stitcher %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :podbay %><br />
      <%= f.text_field :podbay %>
  </div>


    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password %> <i>(leave blank if you don't want to change it)</i><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
      <% if @minimum_password_length %>
        <br />
        <em><%= @minimum_password_length %> characters minimum</em>
      <% end %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br />
      <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password" %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :current_password %> <i>(we need your current password to confirm your changes)</i><br />
      <%= f.password_field :current_password, autocomplete: "current-password" %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
      <%= f.submit "Update" %>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <h3>Cancel my account</h3>

  <p>Unhappy? <%= button_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, method: :delete %></p>

<%= link_to "Back", :back %>
 </div>
</div>
```

**My schema.rb file**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 2021_11_12_082327) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "podcasts", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "email", default: "", null: false
    t.string "encrypted_password", default: "", null: false
    t.string "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.datetime "created_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", precision: 6, null: false
    t.string "title"
    t.text "description"
    t.string "itunes"
    t.string "stitcher"
    t.string "podbay"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_podcasts_on_email", unique: true
    t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_podcasts_on_reset_password_token", unique: true
  end

end
```

Comment: Using a podcast model for authentication with devise means that an account or user would not be able to have multiple podcasts. That doesn't sound right to me. Why don't you use a user model for authentication?

Comment: Let me try to have such a model